There were dogs in the room
a. Dogs were in the room.
b. There were dogs in the room.

c. People were in the room.
d. There were people in the room.

e. Bullets were on the desk.
f. There were bullets on the desk.
Is there any difference between the meanings of the sentences in each pair?
Does (a) suggest that there were only dogs in the room, and, say, no humans?
Many thanks

a, c, and e simply aren't likely utterances (It's just not kind of thing we might say). But they mean exactly the same as b, d, f.

If there were only dogs in the room, both of these statements are true: (1) there were dogs in the room, and (2) there were only dogs in the room. Only the second says that dogs were the only creatures in the room. No humans, cats, parrots, or spiders.

If they find evidence of life on Mars, I don't suppose many if any native Anglophones will ever say "Life is on Mars". But plenty of people will say things like "It's just as I always expected. We now know there is life on Mars!"

You could compare this (we were two/there were two of us); generally there's more than one way to express things but "there were" is the preferred version in many situations.
